# PHP json_decode not working properly?

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony

**This is the JSON data that I received from a 3rd party app:**

```
"{\"transactionTime\":\"2016-04-14T08:03:20-07:00\",\"receipt\":\"X7MLAFBV\",\"transactionType\":\"TEST_SALE\",\"vendor\":\"wpreelpro\",\"role\":\"VENDOR\",\"totalAccountAmount\":40.62,\"paymentMethod\":\"TEST\",\"totalOrderAmount\":3194.58,\"totalTaxAmount\":0.00,\"totalShippingAmount\":0.00,\"currency\":\"INR\",\"orderLanguage\":\"EN\",\"lineItems\":[{\"itemNo\":\"1\",\"productTitle\":\"WPReelPro (Single Site License)\",\"shippable\":false,\"recurring\":false,\"accountAmount\":40.62,\"quantity\":1,\"downloadUrl\":\"http:\/\/ventture.com\/crm\/index.php\/socket\/receipt\/process\/127\/Clickbank\/?utm_nooverride=1&item=1&cbreceipt=X7MLAFBV&time=1460646200&cbpop=43292B5E&cbaffi=0&cname=Krishna+Ghodke&cemail=krishna%40invanto.com&ccountry=IN&czip=411045&userid=2&product_id=1&gateway_id=37\"}],\"customer\":{\"shipping\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}},\"billing\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}}},\"version\":6.0,\"attemptCount\":1,\"vendorVariables\":{\"gateway_id\":\"37\",\"product_id\":\"1\",\"userid\":\"2\",\"utm_nooverride\":\"1\"}}”
```

**Then I ran the following code on this JSON:**

```
$order = json_decode($decrypted, TRUE);
```

This gave:

```
{"transactionTime":"2016-04-14T08:03:20-07:00","receipt":"X7MLAFBV","transactionType":"TEST_SALE","vendor":"wpreelpro","role":"VENDOR","totalAccountAmount":40.62,"paymentMethod":"TEST","totalOrderAmount":3194.58,"totalTaxAmount":0,"totalShippingAmount":0,"currency":"INR","orderLanguage":"EN","lineItems":[{"itemNo":"1","productTitle":"WPReelPro (Single Site License)","shippable":false,"recurring":false,"accountAmount":40.62,"quantity":1,"downloadUrl":"http:\/\/ventture.com\/crm\/index.php\/socket\/receipt\/process\/127\/Clickbank\/?utm_nooverride=1&item=1&cbreceipt=X7MLAFBV&time=1460646200&cbpop=43292B5E&cbaffi=0&cname=Krishna+Ghodke&cemail=krishna%40invanto.com&ccountry=IN&czip=411045&userid=2&product_id=1&gateway_id=37"}],"customer":{"shipping":{"firstName":"KRISHNA","lastName":"GHODKE","fullName":"Krishna Ghodke","email":"krishna@invanto.com","address":{"postalCode":"411045","country":"IN"}},"billing":{"firstName":"KRISHNA","lastName":"GHODKE","fullName":"Krishna Ghodke","email":"krishna@invanto.com","address":{"postalCode":"411045","country":"IN"}}},"version":6,"attemptCount":1,"vendorVariables":{"gateway_id":"37","product_id":"1","userid":"2","utm_nooverride":"1”}}
```

Now, I wish to extract the values as $order[0]->transactionTime (which is first variable in array above). But it doesn’t work. What am I missing?

Comment: Your JSON is *double encoded*. Decoding it once gives you a JSON string, which you need to decode again. Or simply take care not to *encode* it twice in the first place!

Comment: I would think $order['transactionTime'] would be the way to go. But, what do I know?

Comment: Why are you using `[0]`? The JSON looks like an object, not an array.

Comment: You need to read the manual before setting options/arguments without knowing what they actually do: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php Setting *assoc* to `TRUE` returns an *associative array*, not an *object*.

Comment: And "This gave:" when you did what?

Comment: @deceze You should post that as an answer, since none of the other answers seem to have gotten it right.

Comment: Or, you know, just look at my answer that's been sitting there for an hour which outlines that exact issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstly there are no "orders" in array. Your json does not contain array collection of objects but only one object that is why it's impossible to access it via `$order[0]`

Check code below

```
$str = "{\"transactionTime\":\"2016-04-14T08:03:20-07:00\",\"receipt\":\"X7MLAFBV\",\"transactionType\":\"TEST_SALE\",\"vendor\":\"wpreelpro\",\"role\":\"VENDOR\",\"totalAccountAmount\":40.62,\"paymentMethod\":\"TEST\",\"totalOrderAmount\":3194.58,\"totalTaxAmount\":0.00,\"totalShippingAmount\":0.00,\"currency\":\"INR\",\"orderLanguage\":\"EN\",\"lineItems\":[{\"itemNo\":\"1\",\"productTitle\":\"WPReelPro (Single Site License)\",\"shippable\":false,\"recurring\":false,\"accountAmount\":40.62,\"quantity\":1,\"downloadUrl\":\"http:\/\/ventture.com\/crm\/index.php\/socket\/receipt\/process\/127\/Clickbank\/?utm_nooverride=1&item=1&cbreceipt=X7MLAFBV&time=1460646200&cbpop=43292B5E&cbaffi=0&cname=Krishna+Ghodke&cemail=krishna%40invanto.com&ccountry=IN&czip=411045&userid=2&product_id=1&gateway_id=37\"}],\"customer\":{\"shipping\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}},\"billing\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}}},\"version\":6.0,\"attemptCount\":1,\"vendorVariables\":{\"gateway_id\":\"37\",\"product_id\":\"1\",\"userid\":\"2\",\"utm_nooverride\":\"1\"}}";

// Decode as object
$object = json_decode(stripslashes($str));
echo $object->transactionTime;

// Decode as array
$array = json_decode(stripslashes($str), true);
echo $array['transactionTime'];
```

Comment: Wasn't me (I got slaughtered for a perfectly working example), but my guess is because the returned `JSON` is double-encoded, so your `$str` would need to be wrapped with single-quotes to ensure the integrity of the *full* `JSON` response (the response comes wrapped with those double-quotes, but you're using them to wrap the response as a string), e.g. `$str = '"{\"transactionTime\": ... }"';` Very easy to miss. OP should've done a better job explaining.

Comment: @Marcus It looks like he's using `stripslashes` rather than double-decoding it.

Comment: Double-decoding *does* work, in this case. Check my answer below. He's receiving the `JSON` already double-*encoded* from the 3rd-party app. But all he's done is decode it a single time and is left with a string to which he cannot access the keys/values for obvious reasons.

Comment: @KrishnaGhodke it's working but you created your answer and accepted it where's the sense?

Answer (score -1):

Here is i got answer of my question:

```
<?php
$data = '[{"transactionTime":"2016-04-14T05:48:41-07:00","receipt":"AFQ95QHZ","transactionType":"TEST_SALE","vendor":"wpreelpro","role":"VENDOR","totalAccountAmount":40.62,"paymentMethod":"TEST","totalOrderAmount":3194.58,"totalTaxAmount":0,"totalShippingAmount":0,"currency":"INR","orderLanguage":"EN","lineItems":[{"itemNo":"1","productTitle":"WPReelPro (Single Site License)","shippable":false,"recurring":false,"accountAmount":40.62,"quantity":1,"downloadUrl":"http:\/\/ventture.com\/crm\/index.php\/socket\/receipt\/process\/127\/Clickbank\/?utm_nooverride=1&item=1&cbreceipt=AFQ95QHZ&time=1460638121&cbpop=8C0BB1D7&cbaffi=0&cname=Krishna+Ghodke&cemail=krishna%40invanto.com&ccountry=IN&czip=411045&userid=2&product_id=1&gateway_id=37"}],"customer":{"shipping":{"firstName":"KRISHNA","lastName":"GHODKE","fullName":"Krishna Ghodke","email":"krishna@invanto.com","address":{"postalCode":"411045","country":"IN"}},"billing":{"firstName":"KRISHNA","lastName":"GHODKE","fullName":"Krishna Ghodke","email":"krishna@invanto.com","address":{"postalCode":"411045","country":"IN"}}},"version":6,"attemptCount":1,"vendorVariables":{"gateway_id":"37","product_id":"1","userid":"2","utm_nooverride":"1"}}]';
 $json = json_decode($data);

  parse_str($json[0]->lineItems[0]->downloadUrl, $cdata);
  echo"<pre>"; var_dump($cdata); exit;
?>
```

Answer (score -4):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): **assoc**, When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

You've set that to true, so now you have an associative array, and you need to access the keys/vals like you would any other array. But since the `JSON` has been double-encoded, you'll need to wrap it twice with `json_decode()`:

```
$decrypted = '"{\"transactionTime\":\"2016-04-14T08:03:20-07:00\",\"receipt\":\"X7MLAFBV\",\"transactionType\":\"TEST_SALE\",\"vendor\":\"wpreelpro\",\"role\":\"VENDOR\",\"totalAccountAmount\":40.62,\"paymentMethod\":\"TEST\",\"totalOrderAmount\":3194.58,\"totalTaxAmount\":0.00,\"totalShippingAmount\":0.00,\"currency\":\"INR\",\"orderLanguage\":\"EN\",\"lineItems\":[{\"itemNo\":\"1\",\"productTitle\":\"WPReelPro (Single Site License)\",\"shippable\":false,\"recurring\":false,\"accountAmount\":40.62,\"quantity\":1,\"downloadUrl\":\"http:\/\/ventture.com\/crm\/index.php\/socket\/receipt\/process\/127\/Clickbank\/?utm_nooverride=1&item=1&cbreceipt=X7MLAFBV&time=1460646200&cbpop=43292B5E&cbaffi=0&cname=Krishna+Ghodke&cemail=krishna%40invanto.com&ccountry=IN&czip=411045&userid=2&product_id=1&gateway_id=37\"}],\"customer\":{\"shipping\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}},\"billing\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}}},\"version\":6.0,\"attemptCount\":1,\"vendorVariables\":{\"gateway_id\":\"37\",\"product_id\":\"1\",\"userid\":\"2\",\"utm_nooverride\":\"1\"}}"';
$order = json_decode (json_decode($decrypted), TRUE ); // double-encoded so you need to double-decode

echo $order['transactionTime']; // 016-04-14T08:03:20-07:00
```

If you **must** use the returned `JSON` as an object, you need to remove `TRUE` from your `json_decode()` function call:

```
$decrypted = '"{\"transactionTime\":\"2016-04-14T08:03:20-07:00\",\"receipt\":\"X7MLAFBV\",\"transactionType\":\"TEST_SALE\",\"vendor\":\"wpreelpro\",\"role\":\"VENDOR\",\"totalAccountAmount\":40.62,\"paymentMethod\":\"TEST\",\"totalOrderAmount\":3194.58,\"totalTaxAmount\":0.00,\"totalShippingAmount\":0.00,\"currency\":\"INR\",\"orderLanguage\":\"EN\",\"lineItems\":[{\"itemNo\":\"1\",\"productTitle\":\"WPReelPro (Single Site License)\",\"shippable\":false,\"recurring\":false,\"accountAmount\":40.62,\"quantity\":1,\"downloadUrl\":\"http:\/\/ventture.com\/crm\/index.php\/socket\/receipt\/process\/127\/Clickbank\/?utm_nooverride=1&item=1&cbreceipt=X7MLAFBV&time=1460646200&cbpop=43292B5E&cbaffi=0&cname=Krishna+Ghodke&cemail=krishna%40invanto.com&ccountry=IN&czip=411045&userid=2&product_id=1&gateway_id=37\"}],\"customer\":{\"shipping\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}},\"billing\":{\"firstName\":\"KRISHNA\",\"lastName\":\"GHODKE\",\"fullName\":\"Krishna Ghodke\",\"email\":\"krishna@invanto.com\",\"address\":{\"postalCode\":\"411045\",\"country\":\"IN\"}}},\"version\":6.0,\"attemptCount\":1,\"vendorVariables\":{\"gateway_id\":\"37\",\"product_id\":\"1\",\"userid\":\"2\",\"utm_nooverride\":\"1\"}}"';
$order = json_decode (json_decode($decrypted) ); // do not set assoc to TRUE; leave as default FALSE; double-encoded so you need to double-decode

echo $order->transactionTime; // 2016-04-14T08:03:20-07:00
```

Comment: Do everybody a favour who views this question and at least explain the down-votes here.